# Diffusion equation in spherical coordinates for nonhomogeneous boundary conditions as follows?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Do you have any ideas on how to analytically solve the diffusion equation in spherical coordinates (radial component only) for nonhomogeneous boundary conditions as follows?

$\frac{\partial u(r,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{D}{r^2}\frac{\partial }{\partial r} \left ( r^2 \frac{\partial u(r,t) }{\partial r}\right)$   $0<r<1$, $0\le t<\infty$

ICs $u(r,0)=u0$

BCs $\frac{\partial u(r,t)}{\partial r}|_{r=0}=0 $ and $\frac{\partial u(r,t)}{\partial r}|_{r=1}=f(t) $.

I found some similar equations, but here we have two Neumann boundary conditions.

[Solution to diffusion equation in spherical coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131319/solution-to-diffusion-equation-in-spherical-coordinates)

[Solving the heat equation in spherical polars with nonhomogeneous boundary conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849887/solving-the-heat-equation-in-spherical-polars-with-nonhomogeneous-boundary-condi)